# to preserve hard and symbolic link, permissions while creating tar ball and doing same while untar the tarball

Tags: linux, bash

Task: To provide facility to upgrade the system remotely or add new features.

**What I am supposed to do** Create a back up of current environment of target machine and if upgrading fails at any stage, then revert back to original environment.

Say my directory structures are something like this:

> /home/user/project1/....bla bla

project 1  contains symbolic links, hard links, executable files of software and firmware etc.

**My dilemma**

Should I use strategy 1 or 2?

1. Should I copy the whole current environment and revert back if upgrading fails.

   > **example** -> cp -p -r /home/user/project1/* /home/user/project1_backup/
   >
   > **if upgrading fails -->**
   >
   > mv /home/user/project1_backup/ /home/user/project1
2. Should I tarball the whole environment and untar it if upgrading fails. To create tar ball, I'm a bit skeptical about preserving symbolic links and hard links .. and same while untar it.

Could some please provide concrete answer which method I should follow and if I go with tar ball approach what will be the bash command.

As far as I know  `tar -cvfz` for creating tar gunzip **will not** preserve the links and permissions and similarly while untarring the tar ball.
Please throw some light?

Comment: The tarball will preserve information about links, symbolic and hard, and permissions.  The owner and group will be reinstated on extract if the user has 'appropriate permissions' (has `root` privileges).  Otherwise, the owner will be the user extracting the tarball, and the group will be either the one recorded in the tarball (if the user belongs to that group), or will be the user's primary group.  The permissions will be preserved.  Beware absolute vs relative paths in the symlinks.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed. It's a perfectly valid question and it is quite nicely described. However I think it would better fit superuser than SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use the second option: create a tarball; because tarballs have some positive points:

- You can preserve permission/specials files across filesystems (usefull when you backup your a ext* folder to an NTFS filesystem)
- A copy of one single big file will be faster than a thousand small files
- You can compress it.

And here is the command:

```
tar --preserve-permissions --preserve-order -jc /path/to/your/folder > /path/to/your/backup_file.tar.bz2
```

This shall preserve your permission, your symlinks.
And for the hardlinks, I give you this link (http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/hard-links.html)

(but by default, tar preserve hardlinks)

**Don't forget to test your tarball before upgrading your system !!**

(you will avoid almost all lose of data in the case of the archive isn't correctly created)

Comment: Thanks tim for your valuable input

Comment: Another interesting tool: [gzip-links](http://www.argon.org/~roderick/gzip-links.html). Can be combined with tar to compress whole folders.